# Error On Getting Now() on File Save option

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save a file using  `Now()` to get the Time and date by using following methods but on both I am getting error:

```
 FName = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DTMForGIS\" & _
        ComboBox1.Value & _
        "_" & Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & ".xls"
```

or:

```
 FName = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DTMForGIS\" & _
    ComboBox1.Value & _
    "_" & format(now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & ".xls"
```

and here is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: The hint is in the dialog box that you see ;) See what all characters are not allowed.

Comment: More hints: Certain filename formats are not allowed when saving files.

Comment: Sid is right. Clear as a noontime sun... :). More hint, what `Time` is it?

Comment: Thanks guys but if that is the case hoe I can add time to file name? I already learned how to add date buy what about time with "_" separator for Hour and Minute?

Comment: wouldn't `"yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss"` work for you?

Comment: Thanks L42 but this is showing the time as 00.00.00 should i have to use it with Now()

Comment: it is the same regardless. `DateTime.Now` or `Now`.

Comment: `Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh_mm_ss")` should do fine.